# Payment gateway integration using redirection method

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway

I have implemented a payment gateway in react-native which does not have any SDK/library for iOS/Android, it does have the payment API with the option to pay using web redirection method.  I have another restriction, whereas the payment vendor does not provide any confirmation API. Upon payment, the only option I got is to redirect user to a successful page or using payment success web hook.

Currently It is implement following way

```
1. User request for a payment  
2. Send request to our web server (not payment server).   
3. Our web server generates the payment redirection url and pass it to mobile app
4. Mobile app opens a web view and show user the payment page.   
5. Upon payment, we configure the URL to redirect user to a success URL. (protect it using a randomly generated token which is verified
upon payment)  
6. Mobile app detects that users got redirected to payment success page and confirm that payment is done.
```

The issue is, sometimes there is a network interruption resulting in payment not getting confirmed by our web server after the payment is done. In such cases I think web hooks will be appropriate solution. However, I am not sure if this is the best way to deal with this.

Anyone who have implemented a payment gateway using the redirection method. Is there a better way or a different way to deal with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @Saurabh I solved it using hooks, on successful payment, it invokes the defined URL, and I update accordingly.